# How to Create a Tab Hover With Timer

Tags: javascript, css, tabs, hover, mouseenter

It is as follows: (Hover by Mouse)

```
----------------
|    Tab 01    |    Tab 02     
-------------------------------
| Tab 01 - Active             |
|                             |
|                             |
-------------------------------
```

That first tab (Tab 01) is active, But when I move my mouse over the second tab (Tab 02):

```
               ----------------
     Tab 01    |    Tab 02    |
-------------------------------
| Tab 02 - Active             |
|                             |
|                             |
-------------------------------
```

The first tab should wait for 2 seconds before activating the second tab.

I adopted code given in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/QA5Zp/25/

I changed the code with the link above and it is as follows:

```
$('.tabbox').on('mouseenter', function(){
   $('.tabbox').removeClass('active');
    setTimeout(function(){ $(this).addClass('active'); } , 2000);
});
```

Hence when I go to the second fever (Hover by Mouse), It hides the content.

What could be the reason and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you leave a tab, the timeout has already started the countdown. You'll need to clear the timeout, when you leave the current tab, or move to another tab ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/864e1nuj/)):

```
var timeout;

$('.tabbox')
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  })
  .on('mouseenter', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $('.tabbox').removeClass('active');
      $this.addClass('active');
    }, 2000);
  });
```